# Disordered First Contact, decoding string puzzle, C++

Tags: c++, string

This is `Codingame` puzzle. Consider a string `"abcdefghi"`. It was encoded in a following manner:

```
1) Take "a" from abcdefghi, add it at the end of an empty string -> a
2) Take "bc" from bcdefghi, add it at the beginning of a -> bca
3) Take "def" from defghi, add it at the end of bad -> bcadef
4) Take the remaining characters "ghi" and add it at the beginning of bcadef
```

Resulting string is `"ghibcadef"`. The task is to decode `"ghibcadef"` back to `"abcdefghi"`. 
I am overwhelmed with `if`, `else if` statements. And my way of calculating the number of `chunk`s (`a` `bc` `def` `ghi`) in initial string is wrong. 

**EDIT**
This is ugly, but it works. I still think there must be a better way to calculate `chunks`:

```
std::string s = "ghijbcadefkl";
std::string decoded = "";

int chunks = sqrt(s.size() * 2);

// string size if all chunks are filled with letters
int full_chunks = (chunks * (chunks + 1)) / 2;
// string size if all except of the last chunk are filled with letters
int full_chunks_1 = (chunks * (chunks - 1)) / 2;


if (full_chunks < s.size()) {
    ++chunks;
    full_chunks = (chunks * (chunks + 1)) / 2;
    full_chunks_1 = (chunks * (chunks - 1)) / 2;
}

bool beginning = true;
if (chunks % 2 == 1) beginning = false;
int idx1 = 0, idx2 = 0;

while (chunks > 0) {
    if (beginning && decoded == "") {
        decoded = s.substr(idx1, chunks - (full_chunks - s.size())) + decoded;
        idx1 += chunks - (full_chunks - s.size());
    }
    else if (beginning) {
        decoded = s.substr(idx1, chunks) + decoded;
        idx1 += chunks;
    }
    else if (!beginning && decoded == "") {
        if (idx2 == 0) idx2 = full_chunks_1;
        decoded = s.substr(idx2, chunks - (full_chunks - s.size())) + decoded;
        idx2 -= chunks - 2;
    }
    else if (!beginning) {
        if (idx2 == 0) idx2 = s.size() - chunks;
        decoded = s.substr(idx2, chunks) + decoded;
        idx2 -= chunks - 2;
    }
    --chunks;
    beginning = !beginning;
}

std::cout << decoded << std::endl;
```

Comment: Deal with chunking first. Is `sqrt(s.size() * 2)` correct? What if `s = "abcd"`? (Expected no. of chunks is 3 but...)

Comment: I found a way around it in my EDIT

Comment: So your question now is... if there is a better way to calculate chunks? Or have you already gotten 100% on the puzzle? :)

Comment: Yes, I've got 100% now. But I posted it when nothing worked. I'm still curious abt `chunks` though